# Infinitesimal lifting for hensel schemes?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry

I have local hensel ring $A$ and a finite flat $A$-algebra $B$ (which is therefore a direct product of local henselien $A$-algebras) and I would like a section of the canonical map $B \to B / N$ where $N$ is the ideal of nilpotents of $B$.

If such a section does not always exist what are the obstructions?

Any subcases are also appreciated, for example in (krull) dimension zero it is true if $A = k$ is a perfect field but there are immediate counter-examples if $k$ is not perfect (take $\alpha$ an element of the algebraic closure of $k$ such that $\alpha \not\in k, \alpha^p \in k$ and $B = k[T] / (T - \alpha^p)^p$).

Comment: Helpful additional hypotheses might be $A$ is normal, or the degree of $B/N$ over $A$ is coprime to $p$.

Comment: Also, I'm assuming that $B / N$ is flat over $A$.